# Python: How to create dependencies in repos in python projects?

Tags: python, git, pycharm

I am a python beginner, I have Project One which has all the code in a git repo, I am starting a few new projects with their own repos which will all use the generic code in Project One, I don't want to copy paste code. What I am hoping to achieve is separate out the generic code from Project One so it can be inherited/imported in different projects.

```
generic_Code
  -fileOne.py
  -fileTwo.py
```

repo two

```
Project One
  -fileA.py
  -fileB.py
```

repo three

```
ProjectTwo
  -fileC.py
  -fileD.py
```

The goal is I should be able to import classes from Generic_Code repo into files in project one and two. I am using Pycharm and a mac system. On Pycharm, I attached the three projects together and made projectone and two have dependencies to the Generic project, which seem to work but not sure if this is the right way.
Also read something about setup.py but not sure what that is.

Comment: Git itself has very little support for this. There's no such thing as general *dependencies*, but Git has *submodules*, which are rigid and kind of brittle and make people unhappy, earning them the nickname *sob-modules*. Python itself has multiple ecosystems, including `setup.py` files, pip, and virtualenv, and PyCharm probably has its own ecosystems (I don't use PyCharm myself, having a strong distaste for IDEs in general).